# How to create a plot on python using Matplotlib, where all of the zeros from the data set are emitted?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

```
def plot_exam_versus_test_no_zeros(filename):
    """scatter plot, emitting zeros
    """
    marks = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=[2, 3])
    zeros = marks[marks[:, :]==0] = np.nan  
    marks_test = marks[:, 0]
    marks_exam = marks[:, 1]  
    axes = plt.axes()
    axes.plot(marks_test, marks_exam, "go", label="markers")
    axes.set_xlabel("Test")
    axes.set_ylabel("Exam")
    plt.title("COSC121: Exam versus Test")
    plt.show()

plot_exam_versus_test_no_zeros("marks.csv")
```

This is the extent of my code so far. My plot looks identical to what it should, but there are a few differences in the test, as highlighted in yellow.

Thanks in advance.

Here's some photos...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVHJ6.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/de4JK.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1KD2.jpg

Comment: consider filter data before plotting?

Answer (score 0):

No need to over complicate ~

```
def plot_exam_versus_test_no_zeros(filename):
    """scatter plot, emitting zeros
    """
    marks = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=[2, 3])
    marks = marks[marks.all(axis=1),:]
    axes = plt.axes()
    axes.plot(marks, "go", label="markers")
    axes.set_xlabel("Test")
    axes.set_ylabel("Exam")
    plt.title("COSC121: Exam versus Test")
    plt.show()

plot_exam_versus_test_no_zeros("marks.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I forgot to mention that we are not allowed to use any loops or list comprehensions.

Comment: Okay, fixed it to be a `numpy` way, this is what I thought should be possible in the first place :')

Comment: Hmm, I still can't get it to work